# issue related to Validate.php in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
if( !Zend_Validate::is($value, 'EmailAddress') ) {
                                                        $skipUser = true;
 }
...
```

I checked Zend\Validate.php and see:

```
 /**
 * @param  mixed    $value
 * @param  string   $classBaseName
 * @param  array    $args          OPTIONAL
 * @param  mixed    $namespaces    OPTIONAL
 * @return boolean
 * @throws Zend_Validate_Exception
 */
public static function is($value, $classBaseName, array $args = array(), $namespaces = array())
{
    $namespaces = array_merge((array) $namespaces, self::$_defaultNamespaces, array('Zend_Validate'));
    $className  = ucfirst($classBaseName);
...
```

My question is: what are available `$classBaseName`? such as `EmailAddress`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the name of the validation class to use to perform the test, in this case `Zend_Validate_EmailAddress`. There is a fully list of validators in the docs: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html